# Does the product rule for limits always work?

Tags: limits

I just started calculus and I had a homework question that was such.
Find...
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x}{x}$$
So what I tried was ...
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x}{x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{\sin x}{\tan x}*\frac{1}{x})$$
By product rule
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}*\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\tan x}$$
$$1*\infty$$
$$\infty$$
However the answer is the limit does not exists.

Comment: You overlook $\lim_{x\to0}1/\tan(x)$. Indeed, you've only considered the limit from the right. (Also, some take $\infty$ as "the limit does not exist")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit rule always works *when applicable* — the usual mistake is to forget to check whether it actually applies.

The conditions needed for the limit rule are:

- $\lim f(x) = A$
- $\lim g(x) = B$
- the product $A  B$ is defined

In every case where these conditions are satisfied, you have

$$ \lim f(x) g(x) = A  B $$

Usually, this is stated when $A,B$ are restricted to real numbers, in which case the third condition is dropped because it's always true. However, this still applies to settings where values of limits are taken to be extended real numbers or projective real numbers, and in those number systems some products don't exist (such as $0 \cdot (+\infty)$).

So, if you mean to take values of limits in the projective real numbers (the extension where $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are the same number), your calculation is indeed correct!

However, if you mean to take limits in the extended reals (the one where $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are different numbers), then your calculation is in error — it is not true that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\tan(x)} =\infty$.

(the reason it's not true is the same reason why $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$ is not true)

---

All of that said, there is a bit of inconsistency in the usual terminology; that saying that a limit "exists" has the additional implication that the limit is a real number. So while in the extended reals you have $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{|x|}  = \infty$, the usual terminology is to say this limit doesn't exist, rather than saying that it does exist and has the value $\infty$.

---

When you get to multivariable calculus, you'll learn that this is actually a special case of the fact that that if $f$ is continuous at the appropriate value, then $\lim f(\vec{x}) = f(\lim \vec{x})$ — in particular, multiplication is continuous everywhere in its domain.